# angular-translate display key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

In my app I use the [angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) .

On my **index.html** I put the directive `translate-cloak class="translate-cloak"` with `.translate-cloak {visibility: hidden;}` on `<body>` but for the `<div ui-view></div>` content the key is display before my tranlsted text.

In my controller I try to do

```
function SearchCtrl ($translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('../components/search');
        $translate.refresh();

        $translate.onReady().then(function(){
          alert($translate.instant('SEARCH_MONTH')); #display SEARCH_MONTH and not the content
          ...
```

**How can I wait the loading of the module before to render my view ?**

Thanks

Comment: why u dont want to add it to config?

Comment: Because I use a component so it's managed by it

Comment: Can you try something like this ?
`var loader = $translatePartialLoader.addPart('../components/search');
loader.getTable().$promise.then( /* Do your work here */ )
`

Comment: I have `Error: loader.getTable is not a function`

Comment: @sandyJoshi you don't have this error message ?

Comment: Sorry i tested my code found similar error, Can you try something like  `$translatePartialLoader.addPart('../components/search'); $translate.refresh().then( /* Do your work here */ )` or give the plunker link ?

Comment: Perfect @sandyJoshi I used `$translate.refresh().then( $translate.instant("KEY") )` to solve my issue, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait until your file gets downloaded you have to do following:

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('../components/search');
$translate.refresh().then( /* Do your work here */ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, sandyJoshi! After spending a lot of time trying to figure out how to solve the issue, your solution came out. It was implemented this way:

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('file-upload-js');
$translate.refresh().then(
    // detecting a hash/anchor change using jQuery: http://www.rcneil.com/force-reload-on-a-hash-or-anchor-change-with-jquery/
    $(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    window.location.reload(true);
    })
);
```